# Python Extraction Failed while invalid URL

Tags: python, selenium

I am working on a simple extraction Project.

Step 1. It takes URL(my internal site) from the studentid.csv file  located in my desktop
step 2. it runs on chrome and with the url and extracts the "Student.id" 
step 3. And Finally it gives me the output "Student id" in student.xlsx file.

Issue:

It gives me output "student id" until and unless the url is valid.

But it does not give me an output while if there is invalid URL in the "Studentid.csv" and code stops working.

Below is my Code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import pandas as pd
import time
import os

c=1

user = os.getlogin()
path = "C:/Users/"+user+"/Desktop/studentid.csv"
path1 = "C:/Users/"+user+"/Desktop/studentid.xlsx"
print(path)

reader = pd.read_csv(path)
driver =webdriver.Chrome('C:/chromedriver.exe')
driver.maximize_window()

reader['groupid'] = ''
for line in reader['URL']:
    print(line)
    driver.get(line)
    if c==1:
        time.sleep(20)

    time.sleep(5)
    groupid = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="xpath"]').text
    print(groupid)
    reader['groupid'][reader['URL']==line] = groupid
    c=c+1    
reader.to_excel(path1)
```

Error Message:

```
NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="customer-info-VSS_VENDOR_GROUP_ID"]"}
  (Session info: chrome=83.0.4103.61)
```

Comment: Is it correct that you have invalid URLs inside your `studentid.csv` file? If so what would you expect to happen when an invalid URL is opened? Should the program stop? Should it skip the URL? Should it write "INVALID" to the spreadsheet?

Comment: Thank You @BurningKarl, yes, it should write INVALID URL also should give me the other student ids

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it looks like it's failing when trying to locate the element by xpath. You can add a `try`/`except` to prevent the program from stopping if comes across this error.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import pandas as pd
import time
import os

c=1

user = os.getlogin()
path = "C:/Users/"+user+"/Desktop/studentid.csv"
path1 = "C:/Users/"+user+"/Desktop/studentid.xlsx"
print(path)

reader = pd.read_csv(path)
driver =webdriver.Chrome('C:/chromedriver.exe')
driver.maximize_window()

reader['groupid'] = ''
for line in reader['URL']:
    print(line)
    driver.get(line)
    if c==1:
        time.sleep(20)

    time.sleep(5)
    try:
      groupid = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="xpath"]').text
    except:
      groupid = 'INVALID'
    print(groupid)
    reader['groupid'][reader['URL']==line] = groupid
    c=c+1    
reader.to_excel(path1)
```